# Como pasar de línea en un JTextArea

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo un vector de objetos y los quiero mostrar en el JTextArea pero cuando lo hago se sobrepone uno por encima del otro y la verdad no entiendo como solucionarno adjunto mi código.

```
for (int i = 0; i < compasArray.length; i++) {
                        if (compasArray[i] != null)
                            gui.setJtaListaCompañeros(compasArray[i].getNombreCompañero() + "\n"); 
// Inserto un salto de línea pero cada vez que escribe se suponer pone en el JTextArea.
                    } // For
```

`gui` es el nombre de la variable de Tipo JFrame (donde cree mi interfaz y donde se encuentra el siguiente método). y `setJtfCompañero` es un método para setear el texto de JTextArea.

```
public void setJtfCompañero(String jtfCompañero) {
        this.jtfCompañero.setText(String.valueOf(jtfCompañero));
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `gui`? ¿Qué hace `setJtaListaCompañeros`?

Comment: @Sal listo, pregunta actualizada

Comment: En lugar de `setText` prueba con `append`.

Comment: si quieres agregalo como respuesta para confirmar que ta fue respondida gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `setText()` reemplaza todo el texto, en tu caso, si quieres agregar una cadena de una lista (nombre de compañero) deberías usar el método `append()`.