# Listar contenido de un array en un JTEXTFIELD luego de aplicar un Split

Tags: array, jtextfield

Solicito su apoyo debido a que me encuentro realizando un programa en java netbeans en el cual se supone que debo ingresar una cadena de texto separada por un signo en específico, en este caso es el /, una vez separada debo mostrarla en un jtextfield desglosada. Pero por alguna razón se me muestra en el jtextfield solamente la última palabra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código que estoy utilizando en el botón pasar información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_ para mejor legibilidad. Lee [ask].

Comment: Muy parecida a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426536)

Answer (score 0):

En el problema lo tienes en el `for` donde seteas el contenido del `String` en el `JTextField`

Como lo tienes ahora, reemplazas la cadena anterior, sobrescribiéndola.

Cámbialo a este modo:

```
for(i = 0; i < cadenaSeparada.length; i++{
    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + cadenaSeparada[i])
}
```

De esta forma vamos concatenando lo que hay en el `JTextField` mas la nueva cadena que llega.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu apoyo, en efecto me funcionó, además logre utilizar un textarea.append y me funcionó igual. Saludos

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Por favor no olvides votar positivo mí respuesta y marcar el check en gris que aparece debajo.